# `git revert` behaves strangely

Tags: git

When we run 'git revert HEAD~9', here is the error:

```
$ git revert HEAD~9
error: could not revert 45ebde6... AC: added stat summary function
hint: after resolving the conflicts, mark the corrected paths
hint: with 'git add <paths>' or 'git rm <paths>'
hint: and commit the result with 'git commit'
```

The problem is that after we solve the conflicts and commit, then `git revert HEAD~9` brings up the exact same conflict again. We get into this strange loop and never going anywhere with `git revert' and` commit` (just increase of junk commit!). How to fix this problem?

Comment: I think you may be misunderstanding the purpose of `git revert`. What is your overall goal in doing this? Do you want to (a) throw away the past 9 commits, or (b) undo the effect of a single commit from the past?

Comment: If you do `git revert HEAD~9` after you've committed the first reversion, the new `HEAD~9` refers to the commit after the original commit reverted. If you are trying to revert a sequence of commits you should specify the range to a single revert invocation: `git revert HEAD~9..HEAD`.

Comment: @GregHewgill, we want to do a)throw away the past 9 commits.

Comment: Ok, then `revert` is not the correct command. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comments above, what you would like to do is throw away the most recent 9 commits. In this case, `git revert` is not the command you need to use. Instead, `git reset` is correct:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~9
```

This will reset your current branch pointer to 9 commits back from `HEAD`. The `--hard` option also changes the files in your working copy to match the state they were at `HEAD~9`.

Comment: This will only work for the local changes. It the commits we're trying to undo are already in the remote repository you'll either have to 'git push -f' after hard reset and deal with the fallout. Or you have to stick with 'git revert' so that reversed changes are committed and then propagated to upstream.

Comment: Currently we are working on local. The remote copy on github is not exactly the same as local ones.

Comment: After git reset --hard HEAD~9, now it is Master-9. The code seems no change.